# Raspberry Pi 4B screen tearing

Tags: pi-4, config.txt

I want to build a smooth experience on a Raspberry PI, and screen tearing is destroying transitions and animations on a web application viewed in chromium in full-screen, I'm using a 7" touchscreen display, but desktop monitor behaves the same.

I tried manually setting the timings in /boot/config.txt but with no success.

I tried disabling the xcompmgr composition manager and it apparently removed screen tearing only on video playback in chromium.

Does anyone have a screen tearing free config.txt or knows how to remove screen tearing from RPi?

UPDATE: tried compton but didn't solve the issue, animations look smoother but the screen still splits in half.

Comment: Which OS? Have you fully updated?

Comment: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1327 armv7l - Raspberry Pi OS 32-bit, and its fully updated.

Comment: Try updating again. There was a massive update published this afternoon.

Comment: I've been using Chromium on a Pi 4 for a long time now, and never saw the tearing issue. Do you see tearing on a vanilla system as well?

Comment: @DimitryGrigorev didn't cross my mind that the image i got from official sources would cause such issues, what system would you recommend ?

Comment: FWIW, I have a long history of trying to solve Linux screen tearing issues, my point being that I'm rather sensitive to the issue.  I just booted up my first Pi (a Pi 4 4GB) into Raspberry Pi OS and immediately noticed the tearing, both when moving app windows and scrolling in Chromium.  It happens at 4k 30hz and 1080p 60hz when hooked up to my LG C9 TV via HDMI with a microHDMI adapter.  Time permitting, I'll try to solve this in the XOrg config and report back.

Comment: I faced something like this, and i made a video so that it'll be helpful for many.
https://youtu.be/JWhBz7eulh8

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Compositor might help. Type `sudo raspi-config`, go to Advanced Options, and turn it off. A solution specific to Chromium that might work is enabling Hardware Acceleration. You need to go to `/usr/bin/` in the terminal and type `chromium-browser --use-gl=egl`.

I'm pretty sure a general purpose "screen tearing free config.txt" does not exist. If it did it would most likely be already implemented or it would be a popular answer to the multiple screen tearing problems posted on online forums like this.

Comment: i said that i did disable the compositor and it improved quality on some aspects but not browsing

Comment: @AndreiKrestyan Thanks, I updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: AFAIK there is "no general purpose screen tearing config" because there is no tearing problem affecting general public. Or do you get tearing on a Pi 4 too?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I found a few other people who had problems related to screen tearing on a Pi 4 on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/e9k0u3/screen_tearing_solutions_for_the_4b/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/f1nett/fixing_raspberry_pi_4_screen_tearing_by_disabling/. I did also find other forums where people posted similar issues. An example: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/46540/attempts-to-eliminate-screen-tearing-on-arm-on-raspberry-pi-4-buster. I have also noticed similar issues on my Pi 3B+.

Comment: @aklingam using Hardware Acceleration didn't help, also googled the issue before posting and saw the reddit threads, but didn't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

I have a 75" LG TV with an Rpi4 box, the tearing was pretty awful (but I never saw this problem with my previous Rpi3 box.)

Here is what I did, and followed is my configuration which seems to have done the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev xorg-dev
```

Here's my config file

```
[pi4]
cpu_freq=1800
over_voltage=5
gpu_freq=700

[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
gpu_mem=128
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=76
dtparam=audio=on
```

No turbo flag, cpufrequtil or things like that. Short and simple config file.
Chromium seems to work better without any tearing.

For your custom reference, altering the hdmi_mode flag may be the key. Here is an official list of references from the Rpi doc site:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

I'm sure the config file can be improved upon, or my flags aren't 100% correct and are open to criticism, or maybe the drivers weren't necessary---but in the offshoot someone is still looking for answers, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the 64 bit Pi OS has a 32 bit kernel and runs 32 bit apps like chromium. Check which chromium you have, help about chromium. To get the benefit of
a 64 bit system and chromium you need a 64 bit OS. Then use 64 bit chromium and enable
hardware acceleration...
https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/rpi4-ubuntu-mate-hw-video-acceleration.html

It worked for me, no more screen tearing and no dropped frames watching youtube
at 1080p @ 30 fps. (once settled down and do not move mouse during video)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this helps, mine solved by this command.

https://youtu.be/JWhBz7eulh8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I already had Compositor disabled on my current Buster installation. After much fiddling, I found the cause (and also the fix!): Chromium had Video acceleration disabled. Go to `chromium://gpu` and check under `Video decode`. Here it was set on software rendering.

After more searching, I found out that starting chromium with the flag `--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder` the hardware video decoding was now enabled in `chromium://gpu`.

If you need you can pass that command line options inside a file in your home dir called `~/.chromium-browser.init`. This way it will be picked up by all Chromium instances, like so:

`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder"`

Now when starting Chromium normally, the line `Video Decode: Hardware accelerated` should now appear in Green and ready to rock!

Beware, some installations require that the flag be set in `/etc/chromium.d/default-flags`
and some systems require 1 more additional flag:

```
export CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder"
export CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --ignore-gpu-blocklist"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on Bookworm and Buster allways by switching to the other graphics driver - tearing went away. There is an app PiCommander within Pi Apps that allows this to be done only by mouse clicks.